# Dynamic Linq Expression in .NET Core

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, expression

**First**

I cannot use Entity Framework for this because this is a Desktop application in which all database calls are first routed through a Web API End Point. A requirement of this application is that all traffic is HTTP traffic.

**Setup**

Lets say I have an `IEnumerable<BaseItem>` where the `BaseItem` is a base model class that all models inherit from.

We also dynamically instantiate and populate our collection with a dynamic class and dynamic properties that match the column names and appropriate data types of the System.DataTable that is returned from the query.

These dynamic classes also inherit from `BaseItem` which exposes two functions:
`void SetValue(string PropertyName, object Value)`
`object GetValue(string PropertyName)`.

**Issue**

I need to be able to write a linq query that dynamically selects properties from the collection based on the unique constraint columns from the table that the query referenced. I have that in a separate List, where the string values match the dynamic property names on the dynamic class.

I know the solution is probably to use an Expression Tree, but all the examples I find use actual property references, and in this case, the property can only be accessed and set through the GetValue, and SetValue functions.  I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around how to achieve this.  Below is an example of the linq query i want, if I KNEW the fields I wanted to return.

```
var Result = DefaultCollection.Select(x => new { BUSINESS_UNIT = x.GetValue("BUSINESS_UNIT"), FISCAL_YEAR = x.GetValue("FISCAL_YEAR") }).Distinct();
```

Again, I can't write this because I don't know which fields i need to include in the select list until runtime when I can reference the UniqueConstraint List.

How can I achieve this dynamically with Linq Expression?

**Start To Finish Example**

You've populated an `IEnumerable<BaseItem>` from a `System.Data.DataTable` and lets say the query that you ran was `SELECT FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, EMAIL ADDRESS FROM TABLEA`.

The IEnumerable is populated from automation in which a dynamic class is generated to represent a row in the table and dynamic properties are added to the class to represent each column in the table.

Accessing the properties is via methods in BaseItem `string result = item.GetValue("FIRST_NAME")` and `item.SetValue("EMAIL_ADDRESS", "MyEmail@Email.com');`

You also queried `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` to get unique constraints on `TABLEA` and you store it in a `public class ConstraintModel` object that has a `public List<string> Columns` representing the columns that make up the unique constraint.  In this case, only one column "EMAIL_ADDRESS" is in the constraint.

If the user makes changes to the `IEnumerable<BaseItem>` and more than one item has the same EMAIL_ADDRESS, we know that the UPDATE statement back to SQL will fail.  We want to check that the unique constraint hasn't been violated.

At the point the user saves, we want to run a "Validation Check" on the in memory IEnumerable object.  Ideally we would write a linq query that essentailly did a SELECT SUM(1), EMAIL_ADDRESS GROUP BY EMAIL_ADDRESS, and if any of the results had more than 1 value, we know a duplicate exists.  Obviously the above syntax is SQL not Linq, but you get the idea. I can't know at compile time what fields on the BaseItem i need to select and group by, so I need to leverage the Constraint.Columns object and use it to write a dynamic linq expression.  Additionally, the properties on the Dynamic Class are only exposed through the methods that they inherit from BaseItem ... `GetValue(string PropertyName)` and `SetValue(string PropertyName, object Value)`;

Comment: Can you give an example of `dynamically selects properties from the collection based on the unique constraint columns from the table that the query referenced` and `I have that in a separate List, where the string values match the dynamic property names on the dynamic class` (specifically, show us the API that allows you to 'dynamically select properties based on constraint columns' and 'the list with string values')

Comment: What in the world

Comment: It sounds like you should be doing this in two steps. First, get your dynamic query results, then create a new dynamic object with only the columns the caller requires.

Or alternatively turn the resultset into a List<Dictionary<string,object>> or something and remove the items from each Dictionary that the caller didn't ask for.

Comment: @zaitsman - i added a start to finish example, hopefully that is clarifying.

Comment: Accessing data via http API calls is what a lot of people do. That can't be the sole reason why somebody decided that this architecture was the best option. I'm just wondering what is it that prevents your application (not that you can change it now) from using more standard approaches to retrieve and change data (not even using Entity Framework). Maybe there is a special use case that forces you to discover everything at runtime, I'm just curious.

Comment: @insane_developer Right now our primary way to deliver content to users is through our WPF Desktop Application. This makes us closely coupled to the INotifyPropertyChanged implementation. Through configuration we are able to dynamically present users with content that they can perform CRUD operations against. But each row in a DataGrid must represent a public class that implements INotifyPropertyChanged and each property must call the PropertyChanged event.  We use System.Linq.Dynamic.Core to create dynamic classes and properties that match the DataTable.

Comment: @insane_developer - Otherwise we would be required to build model classes that matched each table query that we wanted to give to a user. With this solution we are able to spin up a self contained "feature" that allows for CRUD operation on a table, all based on configuration we dictate, without having to write a single line of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading your `full example` it sounds very much like you do not need dynamic linq at all to do what you're trying to do, but you do need to know what the Primary Key is, why not try something like:

**Update** I have replaced a simple pk lookup with a func PK lookup so that composite Primary Keys can be used.

```
List<string> primaryKeyColumns = new List<string> {"Id"}; // or whatever else
List<string> uniques = /// ConstraintModel.Columns;
List<BaseItem> baseItems = // your baseItems

// Now, wit
Func<BaseItem, BaseItem, bool> equalPrimaryKey = (left, right) => {
   foreach(var pk in primaryKeyColumns) {
     if(left.GetValue(pk) != right.GetValue(pk)) {
        return false;
     }
   }

   return true;
}; // or whatever else

var violators = baseItems.Select(x => {
   return baseItems.Any(z => {
      foreach(var unique in uniques) {
         if (z.GetValue(unique) == x.GetValue(unique) 
            && !equalPrimaryKey(x, z)) {
            return true;
         }
      }

     return false;
   });
}).ToArray();
```

This will give you an array of base items that are duplicated by any unique column

Comment: this solution is simple and effective. But where I believe it fails is: if the primary key is more than one column. Also, while the primary key is by default a unique constraint, and perhaps that is only one column, you can have other unique constraints that include multiple columns.

Comment: @Thrifty2100 you can easily modify it for composite PK by defining a method group, will update my answer. For composite unique constraints, what is your code’s mode of describing those? If you add that I can include an update for this, too

Comment: looks like `var violaters`returns `IEnumerable<bool>`, so i changed it from `DefaultCollection.Select()` to `DefaultCollection.Where()`.  Also each item is checked against itself, so it will always come back as a violation. So I added `if (left.Equals(right)) return false;` in the original equalConstraint Func.

Answer (score 1):

Using a minified version of my `EnumerableExpressionExt` class for helping build `Expression` trees for `Enumerable` expressions, and my `ExpressionExt` helper class:

```
public static class EnumerableExpressionExt {
    private static Type TEnumerable = typeof(Enumerable);
    private static Type TypeGenArg(this Expression e, int n) => e.Type.GetGenericArguments()[n];

    public static MethodCallExpression Distinct(this Expression src) => Expression.Call(TEnumerable, "Distinct", new[] { src.TypeGenArg(0) }, src);

    public static MethodCallExpression Select(this Expression src, LambdaExpression resultFne) => Expression.Call(TEnumerable, "Select", new[] { src.TypeGenArg(0), resultFne.ReturnType }, src, resultFne);
}

public static class ExpressionExt {
    public static ConstantExpression AsConst<T>(this T obj) => Expression.Constant(obj, typeof(T));

    public static LambdaExpression AsLambda(this Expression body) => Expression.Lambda(body);
    public static LambdaExpression Lambda(this ParameterExpression p1, Expression body) => Expression.Lambda(body, p1);

    public static NewExpression New(this Type t, params Expression[] vals) => Expression.New(t.GetConstructors()[0], vals, t.GetProperties());    

    public static ParameterExpression Param(this Type t, string pName) => Expression.Parameter(t, pName);
}
```

You can create custom `Expression` extensions to translate your specific methods:

```
public static class MyExpressionExt {
    public static MethodCallExpression GetValue(this Expression obj, string propName) =>
        Expression.Call(obj, "GetValue", null, propName.AsConst());
}
```

You can build your `Expression` tree as follows:

```
// BaseItem x
var xParm = typeof(BaseItem).Param("x");
// typeof(new { object BUSINESS_UNIT, object FISCAL_YEAR })
var anonType = (new { BUSINESS_UNIT = default(object), FISCAL_YEAR = default(object) }).GetType();
// new { BUSINESS_UNIT = x.GetValue("BUSINESS_UNIT"), FISCAL_YEAR = x.GetValue("FISCAL_YEAR") }
var newExpr = anonType.New(xParm.GetValue("BUSINESS_UNIT"), xParm.GetValue("FISCAL_YEAR"));
// DefaultCollection.Select(x => newExpr)
var selExpr = DefaultCollection.AsConst().Select(xParm.Lambda(newExpr));
// DefaultCollection.Select(x => newExpr).Distinct()
var distExpr = selExpr.Distinct();
```

And you can test it (using LINQPad's `Dump` method) like this:

```
// () => DefaultCollection.Select(x => newExpr).Distinct()
var f = distExpr.AsLambda();
var fc = f.Compile();    
fc.DynamicInvoke().Dump();
```

[LINQPad](https://www.linqpad.net/) is also very helpful for outputting compiler built `Expression` trees and seeing how they were built, or `IQueryable<T>` queries `Expression` member trees.

NOTE: I like not having to call `AsConst()` so I have additional helpers to make that easier as well.

Comment: I'm going to try and incorporate this and see if it works.  i may need to use linq to query my Constraint List to dynamically populate the # of parameters in the newExpr.  In your example it is hard coded for 2. Not sure if that makes sense?  But the challenge is that 1. which properties we want to select against and 2. how many properties we are selecting against - these are both variable and uknown at compile time.

Comment: @Thrifty2100 You can just pass in an array of values instead of discrete values to a `params` parameter and the code will work.

Comment: @Thrifty2100 However, creating an anonymous object at runtime with varying number of fields for the result is of questionable value. Perhaps you could plan to use a `Dictionary` or `List<(string,object)>` or even just `List<object>` or `object[]` instead? Something designed to be varied at runtime.